# Many JIDs to one user on XMPP

Tags: java, xmpp, chat, openfire

Is it possible to have many JIDs associated with one user. For example application installed on many devices which opened by the same user. When message is to be sent to the user all of the devices will receive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have many *full* JIDs associated with a single *bare* JID. So you have alice@wonderland.lit/a alice@wonderland.lit/b etc.

With Message Carbons (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html) your clients and server can negotiate the behaviour you describe.

Comment: I've just noticed you included the Openfire tag, but didn't mention it in the question. I do not know if OF supports Carbons.